# Axios - Unauthorized Bearer Token

Tags: reactjs, axios, bearer-token

Greetings!

So today I'm trying to call an API endpoint using axios. The first endpoinp is being called correctly, but the second one is not working as expected!

What I want to do is, when a user creates an account, he/she will be sent a verification email. So right now, the account creation is working well, but the email verification endpoint is not working as expected. Please take a look at my code.

```
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  };

  const reqBody = {
    formBody: {
      email: emailInput,
      password: passwordInput,
      username: userNameInput,
    },
    reqEmail: {
      channel: 'email',
      channel_value: emailInput,
    },
  };

  // When the signUp button is clicked, call this func
  async function submitFormHandler(event: any) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
  //call the register endpoint - this is working well.
    await axios
      .post(
        `https://website.com/access/v1/user/register?platform=web`,
        reqBody.formBody,
        config
      )
      .then((response) => {

        console.log(response.data);
        // if the user's account is created, call email verifcation

        if (response.data.code == 201) {
          // store the access token.
          const accessToken: string = response.data.access_token;
          const access = {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
          };
          
          axios
            .post(
              `https://website.com/access/v1/account/request-verification?platform=web`,
              reqBody.reqEmail,
              access
            )
            .then((response) => {
              console.log('A Link has been sent to you.' + response);
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        //handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

This is where the error is coming from, I can't call the email verification endpoint. It keeps telling me `unauthorized` - meaning I can't make that call.

I guess I'm not doing something right, maybe the way I'm saving that accessToken in a const, or something.

Please if you have any help, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: When you debug, is `accessToken` the value you expect it to be?

Comment: When I console log the `accessToken`, I'm getting undefined. But on the `console.log(response.data);` , I'm getting the `accessToken`.

I don't know what's wrong!

Comment: unauthorized, It says that your access token is not valid for a particular request. check the token value.

Comment: @Iroro: If it's `undefined` then it's `undefined`.  What *specifically* is being logged to the console and which *specific* `console.log` statement logs it?

Comment: When the account is created, an access_token is created. The access token is there - I can see it on the `console.log(response.data);`

This is what I'm getting in the console.

`

{code: 201, status: 'success', message: 'User Created', data: {…}}
code
: 
201
data
: 
{username: 'irorochad', user_id: '63f8a067ceb213d50133e001', password: '$2a$', email: 'iroro134@gmail.com', user_type: 'user', …}
message
: 
"User Created"
status
: 
"success"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object `

Comment: Inside that `data` object, there is the access_token

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer this here - somehow the response from the console was `data.data` and I was just using `data`.

If you're facing this kind of issues, it could be that you're missing the object name, in my case `data`

Thanks to all those that commented!